# Java Wicket component to image

Tags: java, jquery, wicket, screenshot, snapshot

My Wicket application contains several Wicket components with important (graphical) information. For example, tables/charts and calculated fields in input boxes or labels. I would like to make an image of these components (a screenshot of individual components), so I can send them to someone or to store them somewhere. Is something like this possible in Java Wicket?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, the only way is to do this on the client-side with Javascript. Besides html2canvas there also PhantomJS which describes itself as a “headless WebKit with JavaScript API”.

Maybe you take a look at http://skookum.com/blog/dynamic-screenshots-on-the-server-with-phantomjs/. This could be another way to it.

Answer (score 1):

Since Wicket is a server-side web framework that "only" creates HTML that is sent to the user's browser to be rendered there, what you are asking is not a task for Wicket.

However, it yould probably be done with javascript on the client-side. Have a look at http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/, that seems to be a way to do it.